# failing to create mongodb connection in nodejs 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Nodejs : v8.11.3 - mongo : v3.6.3

following tutorial http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/crud/

**app.js**

```js
const mongoDB = require('./common_mongo.js')
mongoDB.initMongo()
```

**common_mongo.js**

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'onthemove';

let getDb;
const initMongo = async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    getDb = await client.db(dbName);
    await getDb.collection('comments').insert({text: 'hello'});
    //WORKS
};

module.exports = {
    initMongo,
    getDb,
};
```

**user.js**

```
const mongoDB = require('./common_mongo.js');

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {     
    let list  = await mongoDB.getDb.collection('user').find({})
    //FAILS
    res.send(list);
})
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined in user.js**

**Note** : I have tried this earlier with lower versions it used to work ,but with there new versions i m facing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have user.js loaded prior to initMongo actually occurs. So the mongoDB will hold undefined value for the getDb variable.

Simplest possible way to refactor this would be to just change getDb from variable to function so your code will look similar to this:

**common_mongo.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'onthemove';

let db;
const initMongo = async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    db = await client.db(dbName);
    await db.collection('comments').insert({text: 'hello'});
};

module.exports = {
    initMongo,
    getDb() {
      return db;
    },
};
```

**user.js**

```
const mongoDB = require('./common_mongo.js');    

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {     
    let list  = await mongoDB.getDb().collection('user').find({})
    res.send(list);
})
```

even further you can define a getter instead of the getDb

```
module.exports = {
    initMongo,
    get db() {
      return db;
    },
};

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {     
    let list  = await mongoDB.db.collection('user').find({})
    res.send(list);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise before using `getDb`, following code may help you

```
const mongoDB = require('./common_mongo.js');

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {   
    if (!mongoDB.getDb) {  //Check getDb initialise or not
        await mongoDB.initMongo();
    }
    let list  = await mongoDB.getDb.collection('user').find({})
    //FAILS
    res.send(list);
})
```

Comment: Since mongo is not able to create a connection and hence it will always return you undefined.

Comment: 1: hie @arif have a look at  answer ...specially getDb function 
2:i wanted to create common db connection and din't want to check for every request like its in your code
3 :happy coding ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `initMongo` as an asynchronous function. When you call `initMongo` it just returns a promise and the program flow continues. In that case `getDb` is not initialized yet. You can wait until the promise is fulfilled or an error occurrs:

```
mongoDB.initMongo().then(function () {
    // connection succeeded. Do the stuff from user.js
}).catch(function (err) {
     //failure callback. Doing the stuff from user.js won't make any sense here.
});
```